# What are good ways to map out the sequence of user interactions on a page?

Tags: interaction-design, user-behavior, prototype, mockup

In other words, you know the typical sequence for a user based on previous interviews. You would want the next interaction to be easy to find and be a logical next step.

So what are examples or considerations when designing for this?

In the project that I am working on, it is for medical equipment. So typically the user hears about the product at a tradeshow. Then a user visits the site and tends to do the following:

1. Watches the intro video
2. Browses testimonials
3. Reads warranty info
4. Downloads the technical documents
5. Submits contact information to speak with representative about pricing.

My goal was a general visual design of the patterns so that I can present this to the client (as we are still in design phase) when discussing the design of the page.

Comment: I think you missed out the all important word 'client' in the last sentence in the description above.  So what you want is a format for showing the flow to the client - not the flow to the user ?

Comment: @PhillipW Yes, nice catch on missing words. The reason for my question is because I wanted to show a mockup with illustrations so that I can present this to the client because we are still researching. They gave us the business requirements and suggested layout but I was able to get free reign for now, so I want to make sure that I can communicate why research shows that the proposed layout is effective and more pleasant experience to users, so we can get the go ahead to proceed in that direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give users some guidelines of what to do next.

It could be done vertically: just place the information one after another in the desired order.

Or, in a case you have a lot of information, it could be a wizard-like bar at the top of the page which will guide user through the screens at desired order:

[image]

But in a case of the horizontal bar, let user jump from one screen to another freely (i.e. don't limit user movements between screens). It's not a wizard, it's *a guideline*, and in the same time a navigation, which should help your users to choose next steps quickly.

Comment: Ok this is very cool, Alex. I will definitely use this design in projects. 

In the site that I am currently designing though, most of the interactions happen vertically and across pages because the site has a lot of technical documentation that can be read.

However, I LOVE THIS for the technical support feature because it can guide users through a simple way to submit a request, so I am now thinking of having pictures of the steps to supplement the bullet point written instructions. 

Thanks for chiming in.